# animate images smoothly up the canvas from the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I am trying to add images to my canvas and then slowly have them slide off the screen. I have it set up so the images keep getting added and they make their way up the screen. I am looking to add a new image on a canvas on a click, and then this same image slowly glides off the screen.

Here is my attempt below. it adds images to the canvas, and they move up the screen, but its an eyesore, and not the desired behavior.

```js
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = windowWidth;
canvas.height = windowHeight;
var x = windowHeight;


function newImage() {
  var images = [
    'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg',
    'http://www.convoy.me/image/landing/Scratcher.png',
    'http://www.convoy.me/image/landing/push_harder_0006.png',
    'http://www.convoy.me/image/landing/Scratcher.png',
    'http://www.convoy.me/image/landing/Screen-Shot-2015-12-04-at-17.14.41.jpg'

  ];
  var randomImage = parseInt(Math.random() * images.length);
  var randomPosition = parseInt(Math.random() * 1200);


  var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(imageObj, randomPosition, x, 200, 200);
  };
  imageObj.src = images[randomImage];

}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  x--;
  newImage();
}

setInterval(draw, 50);
canvas.addEventListener("click", draw, false);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this code will helpful for you.

```js
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = windowWidth;
canvas.height = windowHeight;


function newImage() {
    var randomPosition = parseInt(Math.random() * 1200);
    var images = [
        'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg',
        'http://www.convoy.me/image/landing/Scratcher.png',
        'http://www.convoy.me/image/landing/push_harder_0006.png',
        'http://www.convoy.me/image/landing/Scratcher.png',
        'http://www.convoy.me/image/landing/Screen-Shot-2015-12-04-at-17.14.41.jpg'
    ];
    var y = windowHeight;
    var randomImage = parseInt(Math.random() * images.length);

    (function draw() {
        var imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj.onload = function () {
            ctx.clearRect(randomPosition - imageObj.width, y, imageObj.width,imageObj.height);
            
            y-=5;
            ctx.drawImage(imageObj, randomPosition - imageObj.width, y, imageObj.width,imageObj.height );

            if (y > -imageObj.height){
                requestAnimationFrame(draw)
            }
        };
        imageObj.src = images[randomImage];
    })();
}

canvas.addEventListener("click", newImage, false);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the loading from the draw function.

I assume you want it to be an infinite image list (well as close to infinite as practically possible)

You will want to maintain a "queue" of images, how many will depend on how often you expect the user to click and how large the images are.

In programing a Queue is an array that has its namesakes function. First in first out, new items are places at the end old items are removed from the start. (does not matter which way as long as the first in first out rule is applied)

For this the queue will allow images to pre loaded and be ready for display when needed.

An image queue.

```
// the images
var imageURLs = ["img1.jpg","img2.jpg","img3.jpg",...,"img_n.jpg"];
var imageQueue = []; // empty.

function addImageToQueue(URL){
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = URL;
    img.onload = function(){
        this.ready = true;  // mark the image as loaded and ready
    }
    img.onerror = function(){
        this.ready = true; // is ready
        this.error = true; // but can not be displayed
    }
    imageQueue.push(img);
}

// get an image if ready from the queue
// return undefined if nothing is ready
// removes errored images and returns first non error if ready
function  getNextImage(){
    if(imageQueue.length > 0){
       if(imageQueue[0].ready && !imageQueue[0].error){ // is image ready and no error
           return imageQueue.shift(); // remove from the list and return
       }else{
           while(imageQueue.length > 0 && imageQueue[0].ready && !imageQueue[0].error){
                // remove bad images
                imageQueue.shift();
           }
           // no need to check error just did that
           if(imageQueue.length > 0 && imageQueue[0].ready){// if any left and ready
               return imageQueue.shift(); // remove from the list and return
           }
     }
}
```

No you have the image queue set up lets deal with the animation. This is a standard animation method.

```
function update(time){ // time is supplied by browser
      ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.width,ctx.height);  // clear
      manageImageQueue();
      drawImages();
      requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

The two functions `manageImageQueue` and `drawImages` do as they are named

To set these function up

```
const queueLen = 5; // number of images to keep in the queue
var displayImages = [];  // current displayed images
var nextImage = true; // if true get a loaded image and add to display list
function manageImageQueue(){
    while(imageQueue.length < queueLen && imageURLs.length > 0){
         addImageToQueue(imageURLs.shift()); // add an image
    }
    if(nextImage){
         var image = getNextImage();
         if(image !== undefined){

              // not sure where you want image to start so I put it bottom center
              // all existing image increase the speed so that they move of canvas
              displayImages.forEach(function(img){ img.yStep += -1; }); 
              displayImages.push({
                 image : img,
                 x : ctx.canvas.width / 2 - image.width / 2,
                 y : ctx.canvas.height - image.height,
                 yStep : 0, // dont move
              });
              nextImage = false;
         }
     }
}
function drawImages(){
     for(var i = 0; i < displayImages.length; i ++){
         var img = displayImages[i]; // get image
         img.y += img.yStep; // move image
         if(img.y + img.image.height < 0){ // if off screen
              displayImages.splice(i,1); // remove image
              i-= 1; // step back so we dont skip the next image if there is one
         }else{
              ctx.drawImage(img.image,img.x,img.y); // draw the image
         }
    }
}
```

Now all we need is the user events that start it all going.

```
function nextImage(){ // you add this to what ever event
    nextimage = true; // flag that a new image is needed.
}
```

And that is it.

This will preload the images, adding an image if available to the canvas when the flag nextImage is true. If no images are available it will wait till there is and add it then. Any images on the canvas will be set to move up when a new image is added.

It will do this until there are no more images in the `imageURLs` array.

Was going to add demo but I see someone has already helped you out, so will leave it at just that. There my be a few typos in the answer.. Add comment if you use this code and have a problem..

:)